# Help building an Query

Tags: sql

I need some help building an Query. 
I have a table "Orders" with 3 fields (IDorder, IDcostumer and amount) and i'm trying to create an List where i add one row for each costumer with the total of amount.

Can someone help me building this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT IDCustomer, SUM(amount)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY IDCustomer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(amount), IDcostumer FROM Orders GROUP BY IDcostumer
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. With your query i've tried to joined another table and converted it to LINQ with linqer. The final code was:

`from c in contexto.Costumers
join s in contexto.Sales on c.IDcostumer equals s.IDCostumer
group new {c, s} by new {
  c.IDcostumer,
  c.name
} into g
select new {
  IDcostumer = (Int32?)g.Key.IDcostumer,
  g.Key.name,
  total = (Decimal?)g.Sum(p => p.s.total)
}`

Unfortunately i haven't understand yet the meaning of group and how it works.
I'll read a few articles to try to understand it.

Thanks ;)